# Как правильно установить JDK

Tags: windows, java

Cкачал jdk-7-ea-bin-b123-windows-x64-22_dec_2010, установил, создал класс, сохранил... при попытке компиляции выводит сообщение в командной строке, что javac не является внешней или внутренней командой.
path - указал путь в бин. Создал переменную хом джава, еще у меня есть инсталятор (я его первым устанавливал) - jdk-6u23-windows-x64. Что можно сделать, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Как и куда прописали JAVA_HOME?

Comment: а если в командной строке писать полный путь до javac, то работает?

Comment: да,работает!!! у меня jdk установлена в диск с:\ jdk- во в JAVA_HOME прописал

Comment: HOME_PATH- C:\jdk1.7.0 - это я создал в переменных системы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\JDK1.7.0;
CLASSPATH=.; C:\JDK1.7.0; C:\JDK1.7.0\LIB
PATH .; C:\JDK1.7.0\; C:\JDK1.7.0\LIB; C:\JDK1.7.0\BIN
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!!! так быстро тут ответил!! 

Comment: и-забыл добавить к слову ответил ))))))) так быстро тут помогли
